# How well does TDD work with small 2-3 month sized iOS/Android mobile app projects with tight deadlines?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tdd

I am a beginner as a Software Developer. I have seen Test-Driven Development approach being talked upon on lot of technology blogs. There was also an SO Post on TDD for small projects.

But I wanted to know, how do people write Test Classes for their code in iOS project? Especially those that have very short deadlines, you have to give a build with new features every week.

And there are scenarios that UI and Requirements keep changing. So do we write test classes for each and every functionality in our Models only?

Or we also test the logic we use to write custom code for controls we create, or for testing code in View Controllers as well?

I want to write test classes, but I get scared trying it out in a live project thinking it will take a lot of my time. So is it that we test all the functionality or we test selected important features?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about programming.

Comment: @halfer we can always move it to software engineering? I asked it like 5 years ago when I didn't understand when to use which one properly. I am okay with closing this also.

Comment: My _guess_ would be that it would be a better fit there, though I don't know their posting guidelines. One used to flag for mod to initiate a site move, but I've had those flags rejected in recent times, so I am no longer sure mods will do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an experienced TDD'er it will be the fastest to write tests for everything. For someone just starting to learn TDD, using TDD might be something like 50% slower* and they might not yet know how to write tests for some hard parts (such as the UI). An advantage of using TDD in a project with tight schedules is that you can release the project whenever you wish, even after every commit, because the program should be working at all times.

* Though in my case the speed of development in my first TDD project, which took about a month, was the same as before using TDD (when measured in lines of code per hour - which isn't a good [measure of productivity](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CannotMeasureProductivity.html)).

Comment: Most of our projects used to be fixed price with tight deadline with absolutely no slack.
We are adopting scrum lately, I hope things will work out.